# how to configure To email for liferay message board portlet

Tags: liferay

the liferay message board portlet has a feature to flag messages with inappropriate content. i found [this](http://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Flag+Inappropriate+Content) about configuring the from part and contents of notification emails. It seems that such emails will be sent to "community/organization admin" (found [here](http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/7170218))

Is there any way to configure a separate email for message board flag notifications? we want something like a moderator role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isnt any way to configure TO email-address for Flag Notifications.

This thing is handled in com.liferay.portlet.flags.messaging.FlagsRequestMessageListener.java in getRecipients method.

In order to achieve what you want you have to override this java class in plugin-ext.

HTH

Thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: @dermoritz: Why not submit this as an idea/feature request to Liferay: https://www.liferay.com/community/ideas. It's possible to change anything - the precondition is that it has to be known as a problem though